# Problem importing dxf file into Blender 3.0.0

Tags: python, import, error

I've been tring to import a dxf file for house renders into Blender 3.0.0. However, whenever I import my file into Blender, the file imports with missing elements and an error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\__init__.py", line 539, in execute
    read(self.report, self.filepath, merge_options, self.import_text, self.import_light, self.export_acis,
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\__init__.py", line 119, in read
    errors = do.entities(os.path.basename(filename).replace(".dxf", ""), new_scene)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfimport\do.py", line 1627, in entities
    self.combined_objects((en for en in self.dwg.modelspace() if is_.combined_entity(en)), scene)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfimport\do.py", line 1531, in combined_objects
    o = self._call_object_types(TYPE, by_att, group, name, scene, False)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfimport\do.py", line 1380, in _call_object_types
    o = type_func(entity, scene, name)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I've tried to convert the file into different dxf versions, still no result. Also when converting to R12, it was successful, however it took a very long time, about an hour and there were dotted lines everywhere. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a broken dxf file.  Try looking at the dxf file with one of the online viewers that checks for errors.

Comment: I’ve used the cad file with 3ds Max and works fine, however, with Blender, it just will not import properly

Comment: Other programs are more forgiving of dxf issues than Blender is.  That's why I suggest using a dxf checker.  Blender's dxf importer has limits.

Comment: Oh I see, do you know any good dxf checkers?

Comment: I thought I did, but I can't find the one I remember using.  Sorry.

Comment: unfortunately same error at the same version here .. have you reach out the solution ?